# Jmockit- mock Private Medhod to return complex object, and then use that for Expectations()

Tags: jmockit, private-methods

I have this situation that I need to test where re-factoring code is not possible (due to organizational reasons :( ).

```
class ClassToTest {
    private ComplexObject createComplexObject() throws SomeException{
        //create the complex object
    }

    public ReturnObject methodToTest(RequestObject reqObj) throws SomeOtherException {
        ComplexObject complexObj = createComplexObject();
        int answer = complexObj.doSomething();
        return new ReturnObject(answer);
    }

}
```

Most of the samples i see are around invoking private methods and have them return a String or an int etc. So here the requirement is a little extra:

1. Both the private method and the method to test are in the same class that needs to be tested
2. Need to call the private method to return a mock implementation of it
3. Use this mock implementation to return the final answer

Please advice on this. All of the examples i see are just to the point of mocking a private method to return `String`/`int`, whereas here i need a complex object(which is mocked itself) and then use it to return the final answer from within the method that's under test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to mock the private method (which is just an internal implementation detail), but the `ComplexObject` dependency. So:

```
@Test
public void exampleTest(@Mocked final ComplexObject anyCmplxObj) throws Exception
{
    new Expectations() {{ anyCmplxObj.doSomething(); result = 123; }};
    RequestObject request = new RequestObject(...);

    ReturnObject ret = new ClassToTest().methodToTest(request);

    assertEquals(123, ret.getAnswer());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just noticed that the abstract super class of the ComplexObject has couple of static initializers that create errors while the reflection call to ComplexObject's constructor is in progress, and so the test fails. What should be the approach for such cases to override abstract SuperClass static varialble/blocks instantiation ?